# How to convince Homebrew that MacPorts is no longer installed

Tags: macos, macports, homebrew

Hi have uninstalled MacPorts, following the official instructions, and then restarted. Spotlight confirms there are no MacPort directories left on my system. In particular, /opt/local/ no longer exists.

And yet when I run `brew doctor`, it says:

```
Warning: You have Macports or Fink installed.
This can cause trouble. You don't have to uninstall them, but you may like to
try temporarily moving them away, eg.
sudo mv /opt/local ~/macports
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if any of the following are true:

- `which port` or `which fink` returns a path to something.
- `/sw` or `/opt/local` exists.

Comment: Thanks. ALthough 'which fink' returned nothing, I manually found fink in /sw/. Must have installed it years ago! While try uninstalling it now.

Comment: For reference, here is the function Homebrew uses to check for these libraries: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/macos.rb#L144.

Comment: @theunraveler Yep, that's what I was looking at while I wrote this. :)